# Редирект со страницы авторизации на Opencart 3, как возвращать на исходную страницу

Tags: opencart, redirect, редирект, login, http-redirect

Вынеся авторизацию в шапку сайта на Opencart 3, столкнулся с такой проблемой что конструкция применяемая во второй версии не работает, как исправить делал ли кто то такую задачу

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', true));
    }
```

то что я пытаюсь сделать

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link($this->request->get['route'], '', true));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было прописать

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->response->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
```